# paperclip is not saving photo details to database

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am trying to create a new user and upload a picture with paperclip. It passes the login, email and password to the database but not the photo details. Can anyone see where I am going wrong? I am using rails 3.06 and ruby  1.9.2

This is from show.html.erb

```
    <div id="pic"><%= image_tag @user.photo.url(:main) %></div>
```

This is from user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :photo
    has_attached_file :photo, :styles => {:small => "70x70>", :main => "250x250>" },
              :url =>  "public/system/photos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

This is the form used on edit.html.erb where it works and new.html.erb where it doesn't

```
     <%= form_for @user, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
       <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :login %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :login %>
       </div>
      <div class="field">
         <%= f.label :email %><br />
         <%= f.text_field :email %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
         <%= f.label :password %><br />
         <%= f.text_field :password %>
      </div>
      <p>
         <%= f.file_field :photo %>
      </p>
      <div class="actions">
         <%= f.submit %>
     </div>
    <% end %>
```

This is from users_controller.rb

```
    def create
       @user = User.new
       @user.login = (params[:user][:login])
       @user.email = (params[:user][:email])
       @user.password = (params[:user][:password])
       @user.photo_file_name = (params[:user][:photo_file_name])
       @user.photo_content_type = (params[:user][:photo_content_type])
       @user.photo_file_size = (params[:user][:photo_file_size])
```

And this is the terminal output

Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-08 13:18:58 +0100
  Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4Qvx+aPv9fpOQYk7aAv5iupoBA8aPBYelcjQPh4aM2I=", "user"=>{"login"=>"meme", "email"=>"me@me.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "photo"=>#>}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."login" = 'meme') LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'me@me.com') LIMIT 1
  AREL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("login", "email", "password", "created_at", "updated_at", "photo_file_name", "photo_content_type", "photo_file_size") VALUES ('meme', 'me@me.com', 'meme', '2013-06-08 12:18:58.686143', '2013-06-08 12:18:58.686143', NULL, NULL, NULL)
[paperclip] Saving attachments.

Comment: Got it. I needed @user.photo = (params[:user][:photo])

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're trying to do too much for paperclip, and in the process accidentally bypassing it. I would change the create action to:

```
def create
  @user = User.new params[:user]
  if @user.save
    ...
```

As a side note, the methods new, create, and update_attributes are designed to receive params[:user] so you don't have to have seven lines of model attribute assignment code.